# Регулярное выражение (соответствие префиксу и постфиксу)

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Помогите пожалуйста составить регулярное выражение, для поиска строки, которая начинается с **"music" "** и заканчивается **mp3"** или **wav"**
Вот примеры строк, которые нужно найти:

```
"music" "song.mp3"
"music" "new/song.mp3"
"music" "my/playlist/song.wav"
```

http://regex101.com/r/xZ8oW8

Answer (score 2):

Для ваших целей regex — стрельба из пушки по воробьям. Это слишком медленное, дорогостоящее и мощное средство для такой простой задачи.

Адекватный код — просто

```
s.StartsWith("music") && (s.EndsWith("mp3") || s.EndsWith("wav"))
```

Сравнение: http://pastebin.com/tH2dPYVk, выдаёт для кода с

> Regex: 00:00:12.4037567
>   String compare: 00:00:05.0182452

для `RegeхOptions.Compiled`, и

> Regex: 00:00:28.8515624
>   String compare: 00:00:05.0148525

при его отсутствии.

Comment: Нет компилятора шарпов :( Что будет, если применить такое выражение- `^music(?:[^\.\n]++|\.)*\.(?:mp3|wav)$` снизил в нем количество операций примерно процентов на 90 по сравнению с Вашим https://regex101.com/r/fG7qX8/1 . Это выражение полностью равносильно `TestStringCompare`, потому что обработка регексами делает лишние действия в Вашем примере - сохраняет группы литералов и делает возвраты там, где не надо.

Comment: Я не придираюсь. Ставлю плюсик ответу - просто любопытно.

Comment: Позволил себе добавить принудительный поиск литерала "точка" перед расширением файла - это вполне логично, но его можно убрать

Comment: Что-то я не то наверно делаю... Просто скопипастил Ваш код из пастебина в http://ideone.com/4Wk6rO и регексы работают вчетверо быстрее.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Mono :) Ideone использует Mono.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Я взял regex из другого ответа (который после этого удалили). Завтра попробую с улучшенной регуляркой.

Comment: @ReinRaus: А чем можно заменить `++` для .NET? У регулярка не компилируется, сообщает «выполняется разбор "`^music(?:[^\.\n]++|\.)*\.(?:mp3|wav)$`" - Вложенный квантификатор +.»

Comment: @ReinRaus: Ага, попробую вот это: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5545721/276994

Comment: @ReinRaus: Странно, у меня вот такая регулярка: `new Regex(@"^music(?:[^\.\n]+|\.)*\.(?:mp3|wav)$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled)` бежит на текстовой строке больше 10 минут (не дождался результата).

Comment: Так и должно быть :) Вся прелесть в "сверхжадном" захвате `++`

Comment: @ReinRaus: Окей, а как исправить? `new Regex(@"^music(?:(?>[^\.\n]+)|\.)*\.(?:mp3|wav)$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.Compiled)`?

Comment: Да, если нет вариантов

Comment: Еще больше разница : http://ideone.com/4Wk6rO

Comment: @ReinRaus: У меня на [вот таком исходнике](http://ideone.com/OD72SK) в release-режиме вот такой результат: http://pastebin.com/pC4tC5J3. То есть строки почти втрое лучше. Но это .NET на Windows.

Comment: Без `RegexOptions.Compiled` получается так: http://pastebin.com/BTyVYUTe

Comment: @ReinRaus: Интересно, чем берёт Regex на Mono: лучшие показатели для Regex (лучше regex engine?) или худшие показатели для строк (хуже оптимизатор?).